# How to change the width of a given square wave with duty cycle 50% without using microcontroller or ramp solutions?

Tags: pwm, dc-dc-converter, boost

Is there a simple way to change the width of a given square wave with duty cycle 50% without using microcontroller or ramp solutions?
Actually, this square wave is switching frequency for my boost converter and I'd like to do PWM.

Comment: google for monostable multivibrator.

Comment: As jippie says, look for a monostable, for example the good know IC 555 timer with astable output, there are a lof of of documentation about this IC in internet. google 555 timer.

Comment: If you are hoping for voltage control of the new duty cycle, you should say so. It's pretty easy with a pot used as a variable resistance, not so much if you want computer control.

Comment: For a boost converter to work correctly, it will already need to do PWM (or pulse skipping) for the control signal. You may be going about this the wrong way.....

Comment: Do you want to change frequency and have the duty cycle remain at 50%,  have a fixed frequency and change duty cycle, or something else?

Comment: Hi, I want to have a fixed frequency and change duty cycle only.

Answer (score 3):

Buy one of these: -

[image]

I've used one exactly how you appear to be wanting to use one and it worked very well and saves a lot of hassle messing around getting component values right. Frequency is adjustable from low Hz to 1 MHz. Duty cycle variants exist that prevent 100% (flat line) or 0% flat lining.

Comment: +1 for not recommending some kludgy analog circuit or a 666 timer.  This is the answer that should float to the top.

Comment: Much cleaner than my solution but I don't see how the OP can synch it with his "given squarewave". The oscillator in this chip is free-running.

Comment: The OP can use this to generate the 'given square wave' *and* have duty cycle control; saves a square wave generator.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMRFwS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. CMOS Schmitt trigger inverter based PWM control.*

Using a CMOS Schmitt trigger such as [CD41016](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/CD/CD40106BC.pdf) you can do this.

- With input 'A' low, 'B' is high, 'C' is low and 'E' is low.
- A rising edge on 'A' causes 'B' to be kicked low via C1 but it is pulled back high in time = \$R_1 \cdot C_1 = 100n \cdot 1k = 0.1~ms\$.
- This short negative pulse is inverted by NOT2 and charges up C2 via D3. Output E switches high.
- C2 discharges at a rate set by VR1 + R3. After the time constant \$C_2 (R_3 + VR_1) \$ NOT 3 will switch and 'E' will switch low again.
- Pulse width at 'E' is adjustable by VR1.
- D1 and D2 protect NOT2 against over-voltage.
- R3 prevents a short circuit on NOT2's output.

Having looked at this you might decide that a monostable multivibrator is a much simpler solution.